# Get configured wifis with ADB

Tags: android, adb

Is there a way to get the configured WiFi-SSIDS from an Android (not rooted) device via ADB? This should be working independant from the WiFi on/off state.

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

generally all the configured **WIFI**s with their **passwords** are stored in **wpa_supplicant.conf** which saved in

**/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf**

but you cant access it unless you have root permission.

you can pull the file by this command

if using windows

**adb pull /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf c:\**

if using ubuntu

**adb pull /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf ~/**

Comment: Upvote because this is a valid answer for rooted devices. I've edited my question. since I like to know if there's a solution for not-rooted devices (e.g. via dumpsys or similiar)

Comment: as far as i know you cant access that partition without root access, still i will try to find if without root is it possible or not

Comment: Non rooted gives message "adb: error: failed to stat remote object '/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf': Permission denied".

Answer (score 6):

Finally found out that

```
adb shell dumpsys wifi | grep -i ssid
```

gives the configured wifis

**Edit:** Only if wifi is enabled

Comment: I've rebooted my phone (Nougat). And still the already configured network SSIDs show up, event if they are not in range. They are listed like this: - DSBLE ID: 1 SSID: "<SSID-NAME>" PROVIDER-NAME: null BSSID: null FQDN: null PRIO: 7 HIDDEN: false. Can you please remove your downvote?

Comment: Is there a way to tell from this dump what security the network has? (ie. whether a saved SSID is password-protected or not)

Answer (score 2):

Not possible. [`WifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#getConfiguredNetworks()) only works when WiFi is on.

Answer (score -3):

adb pull does work on unrooted devices. u need to run the command as root first. try the following:

in the same command prompt box,

-type [adb root] to restart adb as root. click enter.

-Now type [adb shell], click enter. makes sure the prompt shows [root@[device]: ]

-At the # prompt type [cd /data/misc/wifi] click enter.

-Lastly type [cat wpa_supplicant.conf] click enter.

this should dump data of WiFi you've previously connected to on your phone, to your pc screen.

*type in without brackets []

these command works on my unrooted device after running into the “remote object does not exist” issue.

Comment: As one can probably tell by the downvotes, this doesn't work except in very special cases. Using the `adb` binaries from Google, `adb root` is only enabled in development builds. Attempting to run this otherwise will give: `adb cannot run as root in production builds`, unless you have at one time had root access and have changed the value of  `ro.debuggable` to `1`,  or are running a modified version of the `adb` binaries (from some other source).